# IntelliJ - pause a thread while debugging

Tags: multithreading, debugging, intellij-idea

Can I pause a thread while debugging on intellij? What I want to have is something similiar to other ID - right click on a thread and pause it.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You either use a standard breakpoint which will pause all threads when hit or you can use a breakpoint with the [suspend policy = thread](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/breakpoints.html#suspend).

Comment: This isn't useful if you don't know where in the code a thread is executing, and impossible if the thread is in the blocked state (waiting for notify/synchronized/lock)