# Intellij Idea - Multithreading Debug - switching between threads

Tags: multithreading, debugging, intellij-idea

How to switch between threads of a suspended program?

or Any tutorial on multi-threaded debugging with Intellij Idea describing basic features - suspend, resume, switch between threads.

very good tutorials/step-by-step guide available for Netbeans:
e.g. https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/java/debug-multithreaded.html

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Trick is to set breakpoint suspend policy to - Thread.
View breakpoint properties (right-click on breakpoint)

[image: breakpoint properties - suspend policy]

Once done threads will hit breakpoint and block, now active thread can be switched to check race conditions/deadlocks.

[image: switching between threads]

Following code snippet for creating deadlock:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    Thread thread1 = new Thread(null, new MyThread(obj1, obj2), "Thread-1");
    Thread thread2 = new Thread(null, new MyThread(obj2, obj1), "Thread-2");
    thread1.start();
    thread2.start();
}
class MyThread implements Runnable {
    private Object obj1;
    private Object obj2;

    MyThread(Object obj1, Object obj2) {
        this.obj1 = obj1;
        this.obj2 = obj2;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Acquiring locks");
        synchronized (obj1){
            System.out.println("Acquired 1st lock");
            synchronized (obj2){
                System.out.println("Acquired 2nd lock");
            }
            System.out.println("Released 2nd lock");
        }
        System.out.println("Released 1st lock");
    }
}
```

Comment: How in the world did you get to that first screen to set suspend policy

Comment: @DeanHiller - View breakpoint properties (right-click on breakpoint). Updated answer.

Comment: thanks @Amit G.  I thought it was a global setting, heh, but it's hidden there.  I thought that would work differently so I posted this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63249855/in-intellij-2020-1-when-i-hit-play-in-debugger-how-to-stop-it-from-switching-t

Answer (score 6):

Amit,

You may be interested in an alternative threads view of the call stack, enabled by clicking the 'Restore threads view' button:
[image]

A bit of documentation around that : [Debug Tool Window - Threads](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/debug-tool-window-threads.html)

Also, these questions might be useful :

1. [IntelliJ Thread Debug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12581072/intellij-thread-debug)
2. [IntelliJ - pause a thread while debugging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3976878/intellij-pause-a-thread-while-debugging)

Comment: Thanks @AJ. figured out.